# is it possible to repeat a coundown timer?

Tags: java, android, timer

I would like to know if it is possible to repeat a `CountDownTimer` infinitely?

I would like to make a blind test, which change the song when the timer is out & restart with an other song.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jeu);

    int timeinminutes=1;

    new CountDownTimer(timeinminutes*21000, 1000) 
    {

        TextView jeutimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jeu_timer);

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
         {
             long scnds=0;
             scnds=(millisUntilFinished/1000);
             jeutimer.setText( "" + scnds);
         }


         public void onFinish() 
         {

         }
  }.start();
```

My problem is that there's no "restart" function, and I want to restart my countdown infinitely

Comment: I think we need clarification. Why don't you give us some code or whatever you have in mind that we can talk about.

Comment: sorry, i was doing it while you were commenting !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save a reference for the timer:

```
CountDownTimer timer;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jeu);

    int timeinminutes=1;

    timer = new CountDownTimer(timeinminutes*21000, 1000) 
    {

        TextView jeutimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jeu_timer);

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
         {
             long scnds=0;
             scnds=(millisUntilFinished/1000);
             jeutimer.setText( "" + scnds);
         }


         public void onFinish() 
         {

         }
  }.start();
```

Now you will be able to restart it whenever you want with:

```
timer.start();
```

And stop it with:

```
timer.cancel();
```

Answer (score 8):

you can restart it again-

```
        timer =new CountDownTimer(360000,3000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            //Some work

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timer.start(); // start it again after it finishes

        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

calling "this.start" in the onFinish() method also works just fine